# Is it possible to define custom metaoperators in Raku?

Tags: operators, raku

The standard way to define a new operator in Raku is

```
multi sub infix:<operator> ($l, $r) { ... }
```

With different options instead of infix.  I would like to define a custom *meta* operator, however.  The closest I can come (matching the idea of @a X+ @b) is

```
multi sub prefix:<F> (&bar) { ... }
```

But while it compiles, the only way to get it to work with, e.g., the `+` operator is to use an full identifier:

```
(F&infix:<+>)($a, $b)
```

Or are metaoperators definable?

Comment: This is a question asked in reference to https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/iii0i5/how_to_enable_arithmetic_on_my_custom_class/ .  Based on my reading of the `metaops` file in `core.c`, they look very *not* definable without a slang, but I don't know if long term that is a goal, or if they are going to be left to slangs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot currently define custom meta operators in Raku.

You might be able to get one to work through a slang, but with Rakudo-specifc code, and slangs aren't really well document -- the best you can do is google tutorials and examples, docs.raku.org is silent on them :-(

Comment: This is what I assumed, but figured I'd ask the question on behalf of the redditer just to be sure.  There's probably no reason that meta operators *can't* be easily user defined, but they have all sorts of weird ways that they interact with code.  For instance, you can have a prefix meta operator, but the combined metaop + op functions as an infix.  Or `[ ]`, where it's a circumfix relative to the main op, which must be an infx (but can have other metaops on it) and the whol combination acts as a sort of prefix/sub.

Comment: In terms of grammar/actions for Rakudo, that interaction isn't probably too hard to define, but the question is how you define the op.  maybe `multi sub metaop:circumfix<[ ]>:acts-as<prefix> (&main-op where &infix)` or smoething like that for the reduction metaop